# asm.js compilation info in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asm.js

When some `asm.js` code with the `use asm;` directive gets parsed in Firefox, the console will tell me whether it successfully validated and compiled or not. Something like:

```
Successfully compiled asm.js code
(total compilation time 0ms; not stored in cache (too small to benefit))
```

Is there a way to get this information in Chrome as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome doesn't have support for compiling asm.js.  It can still *run* asm.js, like any other Javascript engine, and according to the Wikipedia page for [Asm.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js), as of Chrome 28, the V8 Javascript engine contains some optimizations to improve asm.js performance, but Chrome doesn't take full advantage of asm.js the same way Firefox does.

According to this Chromium [issue tracking page](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2599) and this [official Chrome page](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5453022515691520), it looks like the plan for Chrome is to skip asm.js support entirely and support WebAssembly in a future version.